# Compiling opencv for ARM platform

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, arm

I want to put C++ opencv algorithm on ARM-Linux based camera.
I am able to do Configure and Generate steps for opencv build using CMake.
Then when I try to do “make” operation on terminal I am facing some issue.

```
->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Issue->>>
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.so
/opt/montavista_pro_arm_v5t_le/bin/../lib/gcc/armv5tl-montavista-linux-gnueabi/4.2.0/../../../../armv5tl-montavista-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

I searched online. I tried to do some stuff from link  http://answers.opencv.org/question/33564/opencv-master-branch-compilation-issue/ . I removed ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} option in modules/core/CMakeLists.txt.

But still I am facing same issue.

Can you please help me with that.

Comment: Clearly, its trying to find libz.so. So, either you need to switch off the support for zlib library(configure). Then, again do make and make install